explorer.exe (MSCTFIME UI) stealing focus on Windows 11
I have used Focus Logger on my Windows 11 computer.
Whenever I click anywhere within any program window, Focus Logger indicates that explorer.exe, with a window title of "MSCTFIME UI", receives focus. A few milliseconds later, the focus goes back to the current program.
This is how it looke like when I click around the superuser.com homepage in Chrome:

So apparently this component of Windows intercepts every single click. Why is this happening and is there a way to resolve that?

Is this an issue? What is not working correctly? Is that not normal behavior? Your title indicates something is "stealing focus" -- do you see another window???

have you enabled any other languages that use different alphabets? IME is a technology for enabling input in alphabets that are different than the native one the keyboard uses (for instance, Japanese).

The gist of our questions are that there is no indication this is abnormal or unwanted behavior. Perhaps telling us WHY you have decided to run Focus Logger, what the problem is that you are trying to resolve by using this tool, will help us understand what you are actually looking for.
